# Modal Bottom sheet not re-showing when dismiss called

Tags: java, android

I have added a modal bottom sheet in my main activity  to be displayed whenever the user GPS/internet is off. I have added a LocalBroadcast receiver to listen when the user switch on his GPS/internet from the phone which works fine. So I need when the user switch GPS/internet on to hide the modal bottom sheet and when he switch it off to always shows the bottom sheet.I have tried  [this](https://pastebin.com/B0UdcFLx) which only works at the intial launch of the application that is when let say gps is off the bottom sheet dialog is shown when the user turn on the gps it disappear but problem is after it dismissed for first time when user now turn off the gps its is not getting displayed as expected and broadcast receiver is getting triggered. And here is my broadcast receiver

```
 private BroadcastReceiver locationSwitchStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (android.location.LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {

             validateGPSAndInternet();

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: try  getDialog().dismiss() instead of  getActivity().finish();

Comment: @RajasekaranM tht works fine from the bottomsheetdialog but i need to dismiss it from main activity

Comment: oh ! do you show this alert only on mainActivity? or some other places

Comment: Yes am showing this alert dialog on main activity if there is no gps on else it should be invisible. From my post have added a broadcast receiver to listen for those changes which works fine. My main error is that when the bottom sheet is showing and the user switch on the gps in his phone the broadcast reciever is able to detect those changes but when triggered to close the bottomsheet i get null pointer exception. Guess u understand my problem now

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the static variable in ConnectionBottomSheet for close the bottom sheet on out of fragment.

```
public class ConnectionBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {  

    public static ConnectionBottomSheet fragment;     
    //your code

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            CON_TYPE = getArguments().getString(con_type);

        }
     fragment=this;
   }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
       fragment=null;
    }
  //your code 
}
```

call in main activity

```
 if(ConnectionBottomSheet.fragment!=null && ConnectionBottomSheet.fragment.getDialog()!=null)
    ConnectionBottomSheet.fragment.getDialog().dismiss()
```

Comment: this works but when i try switch on and off am getting this error.                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ConnectionBottomSheet{42fa6858 #2 gps_modal}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1916)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:765)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.jav

Comment: if you off your device your botomsheet will be dismiss. so check fragment is add or not (`isAdded()` will help)

Comment: if the gps was off while launching the app bottom sheet is shown. if I swich on it disappear. if I swich on again the bottom sheet not showing and BroadCastReceiver is getting triggered

Comment: when you called dissmiss() for your bottomsheet

Comment: this is my latest code which toggle of bottom sheet does not work. only works on the first app launch.  https://pastebin.com/vRKDmb3f

Comment: comment dismissBottomSheet(); and try same if issue happened it's not related bottomsheet related

Comment: If I comment on the two now the bottomsheet is not getting dismissed on toggle of on.off bottom sheet. Are you on skype ?